# "IN" or "WITH" for a clock resolution?

Tags: meaning, pronouns

Which is better to use "**in**" or "**with**" if I mention a resolution of a clock?

i.e.

> The clock is available **with** a resolution of milliseconds.

or

> The clock is available **in** a resolution of milliseconds.

Comment: First of all, I doubt any clock would count off milliseconds. (Unless it's a scientific instrument not meant for the human eye in real time.) No human can detect a quantity of time that small. But, that aside, I wouldn't say either. I would say that it ***has*** a resolution of milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

> The clock **has** a resolution of milliseconds.

Yes.

> The clock is available **in** a resolution of milliseconds.

No.

> The clock is available **with** a resolution of milliseconds.

This is probably alright, although somehow not perfect.

The following sort of phrasing might sound better:

> The clock is available with a resolution of either seconds or milliseconds.